# how does the akka testprobe work

Tags: scala, testing

[Reactive programming in Scala](https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001/forum/thread?thread_id=2200) Some background .

Assuming: this testing scenario for actor system. Actor S with a child Actor P. in order to test how S behaves, a test probe tP is created and its Props is assigned to S to create its own P. this is how the test is setup in the background material.

I originally thought P is not newly created  but just referencing tP, but reading from the documentation P created through context.actorOf(props) is always a new Actor. so I am confused how would tP work then ?  did P relay all its messages to tP because of the "Props" stuff? or from the root how did test probe work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion in the course forum

the testprobe and persistor created using the testprobe REF are different actors. persistor will relay the messages it received in between.